# Replace detailview field before insert

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to edit an hidden field value of detailsview before inserting?  I want to replace it with another value. Which event can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ItemInserting` event.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done on the ItemInserting event of the DetailsView control. Here's how:

```
Private Sub DetailsView1_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemInserting
    e.Values("ProductName") = "Your New Value"
End Sub
```

Basically e.Values is a collection of ordered KetValuePairs which contain your DetailsView insert form entries. You can reference them by index or by key. In the example above I reference them by key - "ProductName" in my case since I used the Products table of the Northwind database. Hope this helps...